# Detecting scroll direction using scrollmagic JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollmagic

I am using scrollMagic JS for adding some feature with my web application. Trying to detect scroll direction using [scrollmagic](https://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#event:enter) JS. Scrolldirection has three state PAUSED, FORWARD and REVERSE, but I am getting PAUSED only while scrolling up and down

Below is my code snippet for your review.

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#c-story-header__scrolltrigger", triggerHook: 0.5, duration: '100%'})
.on("enter", function (e) {
console.log(e.scrollDirection);
}).addTo(controller);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `progress` event instead of the `enter` event. `enter` will only fire on... `enter`

[Scrollmagic Scene progress event](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#event:progress)

```
.on('progress' ,function(e){
  console.log(e.progress)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

using `progress` event

```
.on('progress' ,function(e){
   console.log(e.scrollDirection)
})
```

returns:
FORWARD | REVERSE